# Como setar um combobox com valores iniciais ? Utilizando javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ola, possuo um código em linguagem Go onde temos uma página web feita em html + javascript + jquery.
Preciso setar os valores iniciais de um combobox de acordo com o que está salvo em arquivo json.
Abaixo segue a função que é chamada no código javascript para criação do combobox:

```js
$crudjs.dropdownInput = function(map) {
  return function(value, name, key) {
    return $("<select />")
      .append(Object.keys(map).map(function(key) {
        return $("<option/>")
          .val(key)
          .html(map[key]);
      }))
      .val(value)
      .change(function() {
        if (key) {
          valor = $(this).val();

          if (valor == 0) {
            $crudjs.page.itemField(key, name, "Wifi");


          } else if (valor == 1) {
            $crudjs.page.itemField(key, name, "RF433");

          }

        } else {
          $crudjs.page.field(name, $(this).val());
          mais ");
        }
      });
  }
}
```

como é um código que já peguei pronto para modificar, não estou conseguindo evoluir nessa questão.